# 403 forbidden ошибка

Tags: html, apache

Пользуюсь shared hosting. С помощью FileZilla в `public_html` перетащил файлы, там `index.html` и так далее. Я раньше делал так и все работало, а сейчас пишет:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>   Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Права на файлы: cgi_bin в public_html, 755 было, сделал 644. В чем проблема прошу очень помогите

Comment: Какой-то поток сознания, с трудом понимаю.

Comment: "сделал 644 " - возможно в этом проблема... а вообще ситуацию более понятно изложите...

Comment: Написано же — «Server unable to read htaccess file», его права проверьте

Comment: А файл .htaccess есть в папке public_html? Какое его содержимое?

Comment: Да есть .htaccess я нажал на FileZilla права доступа к файлу и 644 сделал числовое значение и автоматически 755 стало